# How can I put tick marks and tooltip on slider (HTML5) for GWT

Tags: html, gwt, slider, tooltip

I do want put tick marks (number/character) and tooltip on my Slider without using any 3rd party library or JQuery. Can anyone give me some idea? (I'm using GWT)

Thanks,

Notes : I've used this code for tooltip, but it doesn't work for very well. When I move the mouse first time it shows, but not 2nd or 3rd..., I mean it is not refreshing all the time. But every time, it is print out on console. By the way, after couple of test, setTitle is working on IE, but it doesn't work on FireFox(26) and Chrome(39).

```
  @Override
  public void onMouseMove(
      MouseMoveEvent event) {
    if (dragging == true) {
      hSlider.setTitle(hSlider.getPropertyString("value") + " onMouseMove");
      sliderTextBox.setValue(hSlider.getPropertyString("value"));
      System.out.println(hSlider.getPropertyString("value") + " onMouseMove");
    }
  }
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' xmlns:u="urn:import:com.ali.slider.client.utils.widget">

    <ui:with field="res"
        type="com.ali.slider.client.resources.AllResources" />
    <ui:with field="img" type="com.ali.slider.client.resources.AllImages" />

    <ui:style>
    .panel {
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .input[type='range'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
        background-color: pink;
        height: 30px;
    }

    .input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: blue;
        border: 3px solid green;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px red;
        height: 10px;
        width: 150px;
    }

    .input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: blue;
        /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.5);*/
        border: 3px solid green;
        height: 50px;
        width: 10px;
    }

    .input[type='range']:active::-moz-range-thumb {
        background: orange;
        border: 3px solid red;
        /*box-shadow:0 0 0 2px pink;*/
    }

    .input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: transparent;
        background-color: blue;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.5);
        border: 3px solid red;
        height: 50px;
        width: 20px;
    }

    .input[type='range']:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        background: orange;
        border: 1px solid #0940fd;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #6fb5f1;
    }

    .input4 {
        margin: 10px 10px 30px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Junction;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: darkgrey;
    }

    </ui:style>

    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{res.sliderBarStyle.sliderContainer}">
        <div>
            <input ui:field="hSlider" type="range" min="10" max="100"
                value="20" step="10" name="slider" class="{style.input}"></input>
            <g:TextBox ui:field="sliderTextBox" value="0" styleName="{style.input4}"></g:TextBox>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```